# Car Jump Started in wrong way

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module, misfire, fuel-injectors

We switched the jumper cables when trying to jump start my Altezza 4 cylinder. Main fuse and other fuses were blown. I replaced all the damaged fuses and battery. When we eventually got the car to start, it started misfiring. I replaced the bad ignition coil and spark plugs. Upon replacement two other coils ceased to function. The one I had replaced was now functional and now two coils, in cylinder 1 and 4 were unresponsive.  I proceeded to replace those two coils. There was no change in the misfiring i.e only just two coils were responsive, in cylinder 2 and 3. I then proceeded to replace the crankshaft position sensor as the diagnosing machine had given an error code for it. There was no change, I then replaced the ECU system. With the new ECU system, sometimes when we start the car in the morning when the engine is cold, all four coils work but after warming up only 3 coils out of the 4 work.  I proceeded to lap my cylinder head and changed piston rings. The car is back to firing with just two ignition coils. The injector in cylinder one also seems faulty. HELP!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: While it's hard to predict the damage done from an incorrect polarity jump attempt the damage is generally in the electrical systems rather than the mechanicals. Have you checked your alternator is behaving normally?

Comment: The alternator seems to be working fine.. I asked one auto electrician to come and try to identify any problem with the electrical system, but unfortunately there is no engine light to indicate that there is any problem with the systems associated to the engine